# Using join to match table rows based on a date falling within a range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to map the World Bank country income levels to a dataset.  The income levels change year to year and I need to map the appropriate income level to a transaction using the transaction's country and date.

The following tables illustrate the layout and problem:

```
Example - Table 1                  Table 2
-----------------                  ----------------------------------------
|ISOCountryCode3, PODate       |   |CountryAlpha3, StartDate,  EndDate,    IncomeClass|
|CIV,            '2009-11-01'  |   | CIV,          1989-10-02, 1989-09-12,     lower  |
|ALB,            '2007-01-04'  |   | CIV,          2009-01-01, 2010-01-01,     lower  |  
                                   | CIV,          2010-01-02, 2011-01-01,     middle |
```

The system should return:

```
|CIV, '2009-11-01', lower|
|...
```

Here's the SQL that I've tried so far

```
SELECT mergestandard.*,incomeclassifications.IncomeClass 
FROM `mergestandard`
LEFT OUTER JOIN  incomeclassifications 
ON mergestandard.ISOCountryCode3 = incomeclassifications.CountryAlpha3
AND mergestandard.PODate<=incomeclassifications.EndDate
AND mergestandard.PODate>=incomeclassifications.StartDate
```

Unfortunately, the system keeps returning null in the incomeclass field.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are EndDate and PODate or StartDate the same type?

Comment: @Mihai makes a good point, it looks like one table has quotes around the dates and the other doesn't. Is one column a date and the other a string?

Comment: Hi.  The dates are all just "Date" type.  I will say that the mergedstandard is actually a view.  Not sure if that makes any difference.  The view is a UNION query that merges data from a few tables - all having a PODate formated in the Date form.  Just checked the view PODate standard and it is also 'Date".

Comment: I don't know if the quotes around that column actually make a difference even if they are the same type,somebody could answer that.

Comment: It works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d31a5/1 The second row has null in the incomeclass because there's no match for the country code `ALB` in the second table.

Comment: Or could the comma ruin the comparison?

Comment: I think you folks are all getting hung up on the way he chose to present the data to us. The quotes and commas are just presentation, not part of the data.

Comment: BINGO!  GOT IT.  Thanks @ Barmar!  Your example was extremely helpful.  I used it in detail.  I think the issue was that the first table contained 35,000 rows and the second table contained >5,000 rows.  For some reason, when I indexed the second table it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually use mySql, but I would try this:

```
SELECT mergestandard.*,incomeclassifications.IncomeClass 
FROM `mergestandard`
LEFT OUTER JOIN  incomeclassifications 
ON mergestandard.ISOCountryCode3 = incomeclassifications.CountryAlpha3
WHERE
mergestandard.PODate<=incomeclassifications.EndDate
AND mergestandard.PODate>=incomeclassifications.StartDate
```

The first part would give you

```
|CIV, '2009-11-01', lower|
|CIV, '2009-11-01', lower|
|CIV, '2009-11-01', middle|
|...
```

Which actually also includes the dates

```
|CIV, '2009-11-01', lower| 1989-10-02, 1989-09-12
|CIV, '2009-11-01', lower| 2009-01-01, 2010-01-01
|CIV, '2009-11-01', middle| 2010-01-02, 2011-01-01
|...
```

Then use the where clause to filter what you want.

```
|CIV, '2009-11-01', lower| 2009-01-01, 2010-01-01
```

Comment: If you're going to compare with values in the second table, there's no point in using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, since the comparison will filter out all the non-matching rows that are the point of using an outer join.